CommandException : java.io.IOException: UT10029 : stream is closed
When ever try to write a data in a httpservletResponse file   It throwing stream is closed exception its happing only when the file size is more than 10 mb.
Tried adding write timeout to 600000 but still same issue
Below is my code exception is getting in while loop when os.write is calling. Whenever file size is less or has less number of records then not throwing any exceptions file is getting downloaded
InputStream fis = null;
        OutputStream os = nul;
        try {

      //some response.set content type set header and add hearder is happing then

            file = generatereport();// in this method  data is fetching from data base and writing to the file
            Long fileLength = Long.valueof(file.length());
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            response.setContentLength(fileLength.intValue());
            os = response.getOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int count = fis.read(b);
            while (count > -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, count);  //getting exception here
                count = fis.read(b);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new CommandException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
                if (os != null) {
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                }
                response.flushBuffer();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(dataSource)) {
                DataSourceSwitcher.restoreDataSource(dataSource);
            }`
        


Tried adding the IOUtils.capyLarge(fis,os);
Instead of while still same issue

Seems like maybe the server is set to not accept data of more than 10 mb

Don’t set the content length. Java does that automatically. Flush before close is redundant. I suggest you use chunked streaming mode,

Btw you can use Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream()) instead of coding it yourself.
